# How to create folder programmatically in DotNetNuke and assign permission to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dotnetnuke

I have created a folder in DotNetNuke programmatically on the root portal directory. 
I just want to assign permissions to it only one time, for example I want to make it read only for authenticated users. Any advice on how to accomplish this using C# or VB.NEt?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly involved and convoluted:

```
var folderController = new FolderController();
var folderId =
    folderController.AddFolder(
        new FolderInfo(
            portalId, 
            folderName, 
            (int)FolderController.StorageLocationTypes.InsecureFileSystem,
            isProtected: false, 
            isCached: false, 
            lastUpdated: Null.NullDate));
var folder = folderController.GetFolderInfo(portalId, folderId);
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder.PhysicalPath);

var permissionController = new PermissionController();
var writePermission = permissionController.GetPermissionByCodeAndKey("SYSTEM_FOLDER", "WRITE").Cast<PermissionInfo>().Single();
var registeredUserRole = new RoleController().GetRoleByName(folder.PortalID, "Registered Users");
folder.FolderPermissions.Add(new FolderPermissionInfo
    {
        FolderID = folder.FolderID,
        PermissionID = writePermission.PermissionID,
        RoleID = registeredUserRole.RoleID,
        UserID = Null.NullInteger,
        PermissionKey = writePermission.PermissionKey,
        AllowAccess = false
    });
```

Comment: It is indeed a bit convoluted but you answer makes it easier to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: bdukes - is there a way to set all users to permissions like read files

Comment: @codemypantsoff You should be able to set the `RoleID` to `int.Parse(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.glbRoleAllUsers, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to set the permission for all users.  The read permission's key is `"READ"`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code didn't add permissions for me into the database.

```
folder.FolderPermissions.Add(new FolderPermissionInfo
{
    FolderID = folder.FolderID,
    PermissionID = writePermission.PermissionID,
    RoleID = registeredUserRole.RoleID,
    UserID = Null.NullInteger,
    PermissionKey = writePermission.PermissionKey,
    AllowAccess = false
});
```

I had to use:

```
 FolderManager.Instance.SetFolderPermission(folder, 6, registeredUserRole.RoleID);
```

- folder = FolderInfo
- 6 = The permission id, write in this case (this will also add the
  permissions: view/browse).
- registeredUserRole.RoleID = the role you want to give the folder
  permissions to.